# How to add a record with other multiple data ( 1 to Many ) relationship in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, one-to-many

So basically i have a FactoryMachine Table and Generators Table . They are linked as 1 to Many relationship.
FactoryMachines has a PK of Generators .
How make a Form that can take multiple Generators for the same Factory machine ?
I want something like the following :

A Form called 
AddingFactoryMachinesForm
That has a ComboBox with the existing Generators and whenever a generator is selected anther Combobox Pops to allow the selection of anther generator and so on .

Im using MS- Access 2016

Comment: If each factory can have multiple generators but each generator can associate with only 1 machine then save MachineID into Generators table. If each machine can have multiple generators and each generator can associate with multiple machines, that is a many-to-many relationship and requires a third "junction" table.

Comment: I already done that but my question is how to make a Form that can allow me to add multiple Generators to the Factory machines using somthing like multiple Comboxes

Comment: Is FactoryMachines a table of all machines in factory - each record is unique for a single machine? Each machine can have multiple generators? Each generator can associate with only 1 machine? You say FactoryMachines has field for generator - I am saying that is backwards. Your description of 'multiple comboboxes' makes no sense.

Comment: First sorry for no replying in while,

Answer (score 0):

you could design a form like this:

[image]

save each FactoryMachine as a combobox item
and each Generator as a checkbox
the database will be like this:

[image]

you could edit this design to meet your needs

Comment: This is not a normalized data structure. It might be workable or might be a royal pain.